# Using htmlspecialchars when not outputting to html

Tags: php

For example if i use `$id= $_GET['id'];` and then i use that `$id` as a condition for an if statement, do i have to use htmlspecialchars on `$id`?

e.g.

```
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

if($id) {
//code
}
```

Is htmlspecialchars needed, even though no html is being output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You only need to HTML-escape data if you are outputting it into an HTML context, and the data *may* contain characters which have a special meaning in HTML (e.g. `<`, `>`, `"`) and you do not want those characters to break your HTML structure.

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).